# close Bootstrap Modal after click button inside model

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

in my asp page i have the following:

```
 <ContentTemplate> <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <asp:Label ID="lblModalBody" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSavedata" CssClass="btn btn-info"> Text="Save"/>

                    <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </div> </div>
```

also i have another link to show Modal from code behind

```
Protected Sub btn_DeleteQuote_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_PrintQuote.ServerClick

lblModalTitle.Text = "Validation Errors List for HP7 Citation"
lblModalBody.Text = "This is modal body"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal({backdrop:'static', keyboard: false});", True)
upModal.Update()
```

End Sub

Now i want when i click on button btnSavedata (this butoon inside modal) i want to update some content inside my page (this content outside modal) then close the modal
i want this using code behind on btnSavedata_click event

Comment: do explain your question properly, it's not very clear!!!

Comment: i just gave u an answer, if u need any help regarding this you can comment and explain your question

Comment: My question is i want to close my modal after click save button using codebehind.

Comment: any body can help me

Comment: what do you want to do on save button click?

Comment: save data in DB then close Modal

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal('hide');", True)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
[http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp][1]
```

Perfect example of `Asp.net Modal`

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">SAVE</button>
```